stripe dashbaord showing 400 even though stripe listen cli is retuning 200
As a sanity check, I am immediately returning a status 200. as you can see in the screenshots below, my cli says everything is okay and returning 200 back to stripe, but in my dashboard I am getting status 400s. This is for a django app. does the dashboard response even matter if the cli is picking it up?
We have constructed the even
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class StripeWebhook(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse({status: "success"},status=200)
        #all the code below is our normal logic. we are just trying to do a sanity test
        #to see if the dashboard picks up the 200
        print('received payment. in webhook')
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_TEST_SECRET
        event = None
        payload = request.body        
        sig_header = request.META["HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"]
        try:
            event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
                payload, sig_header, 'settings.WEBHOOK_SECRET'
            )
        except ValueError as e: 
            print("aaa")
            print(e)
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
        except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
            print('bbb')
            print(e)
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
        
        
        if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
            print('payment success')
        elif event['type'] == 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
            # Handle failed payment intent event
            print('payment failed')
            return HttpResponse('something went wrong', status=400)
        return HttpResponse({'status': 'success'})



(https://i.sstatic.net/BUgJsnzu.png) #stipe cli logs
(https://i.sstatic.net/itoTZ4bj.png) #stipe dashboard
we tried immediately returning a 200 status to stripe.

I am a bit confused what you are asking, you don't post 200 to stripe...in your code you are basically only throwing return HttpResponse(status=400) when there is an error, which means based on quick look, that you need to figure out the error and fix it. I'd bet your transaction is erroring out and stripe is giving you an error response. Also just curious why are you posting a 400 response (client error) when this is likely a backend one with your processing of the transaction?

what i mean to say is that even when we directly send a 200 directly in the first line of the post function from the webhook, stripe shows a 400 on the dashboard even though in my cli it says 200. you can check the links to the screenshots to see what i mean.

You should always return 200 to Stripe whenever you successfully receive a webhook. That indicates the HTTP request was received, not that there was an error parsing the webhook itself. Any errors that you need to handle should be handled within the webhook handler after you return a 200.

I understand that. I am just asking why is there a discrepancy between my CLI and my dashboard for the same responses
